# Symfony2 sessions not working as expected / session keeps timing out

Tags: php, symfony, session

My Symfony2 application displays a main page, and from there on it primarily uses AJAX requests to display content to the user via modals.

I've noticed that after the user is idle for some period of time (around 15-30 minutes) the session is destroyed, and the user is logged out and needs to log in again. This is incredibly frustrating, since I can't expect users to log in again every time they've been idle for a few minutes.

As far as I can tell, this problem should not be happening according to my `config.yml` file, which is as follows:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 0      # Session lifetime in seconds
        gc_maxlifetime: 28800   # Seconds after which data will be seen
                                # as garbage and potentially cleaned up
        handler_id:  ~          # Current using the default session handler
```

For completeness, my current environment is as follows:

- Symfony 2.4.8
- PHP 5.4
- Session handler: default (file-based according to `php.ini`)
- Ubuntu Server 12.10

Summary:

- **What should be happening:** users should not be logged out, even after being idle for hours
- **What is actually happening:** users are being logged out after being idle for 15-30 minutes

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you check the coockie lifetime that is actually set in the browser?

Comment: The cookie expiry date is not set (which means that it's for the duration of the browser being open). As far as I can tell, the problem is with Symfony destroying the session before it's actually expired.

Comment: be sure your not using `$_SESSION` to keep track of your vars when using the session from symf

Comment: I'm not touching the session at all. It's all being handled by Symfony, and solely for keeping the user logged in. I'm not storing any data in the session anywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The problem:**

It turns out that on Debian / Ubuntu systems, there is a system cronjob which runs every 30 minutes, cleaning out all "old" sessions. Herein lies the problem.

The cronjob doesn't actually know what constitutes "old". The cronjob simply calls a PHP-CLI script located at `/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime` which then removes all session files that exceed a certain age. Since the script is involved by PHP-CLI, and independently of Symfony2, it has no idea what values you specified for `gc_maxlifetime` and `cookie_lifetime` in your Symfony2 config file. Instead, if just defaults to using the `session.cookie_lifetime` and `session.gc_maxlifetime` values from the `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` config file, which by default, is 24 minutes. So no matter what you specify in your Symfony2 config file, if you are idle for too long, your session will be removed.

**The solution:**

- Either delete the cronjob file at `/etc/cron.d/php5` or,
- Store your sessions in a database where they can't be touched by the cronjob

Comment: I'm not root so I can't do the first solution, so how can I make symfony store session in database and make it's lifetime more longer?

Answer (score 1):

I set remember me cookie set to default, and then in security.yml

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                remember_me: true
            remember_me:
                key: mycookie
                lifetime: 2592000 # 30 days
                path: /
                domain: ~
                always_remember_me: true
```

Answer (score 1):

My first answer seems not suitable for your issue. Maybe this one will help.

Do you clear Symfony cache between your requests ?

Extract of [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/reference/configuration/framework.html#save-path) :

> **save_path**
>
> type: *string* default: ***%kernel.cache.dir%/sessions***
>
> This determines the argument to be passed to the save handler. If you
>   choose the default file handler, this is the path where the session
>   files are created. For more information, see Configuring the Directory
>   where Session Files are Saved.
>
> You can also set this value to the *save_path* of your php.ini by setting the value to *null*.

By default, Symfony stores sessions in the cache directory that is emptied while clearing cache...

Answer (score 0):

Extract of [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-lifetime) :

> **cookie_lifetime**
>
> type: *integer* default: *null*
>
> This determines the lifetime of the session - in seconds. It will use
>   null by default, which means session.cookie_lifetime value from
>   php.ini will be used. **Setting this value to 0 means the cookie is
>   valid for the length of the browser session.**

So, 0 is not infinite session BUT browser session... You should define a big amoutn of seconds and test it.

Comment: I've tested it previously by setting it to the same value as gc_maxlifetime, which was 8 hours, and I still had the same problem.

Comment: Also, by setting it to 0, it should remain valid for at least as long as the browser is open, which isn't the case. The users are not closing their browser, and they're still being logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Travis T, I went the simplest route of all. I said

## nano /etc/cron.d/php5

This opened the file showing the tremendously long  crontab code that purges your session by default every 30 mins. The script was preceded by a #, and all I did was uncomment both lines by removing the #. So:

```
#  Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
#  09, 39, *  * * *  root  @[ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [  etc 
   it's a long file.....]
```

I just removed the 2 #'s in front of Look and 09. That's it !